# Add an Int column to a Timestamp as Minutes

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've been working on some transformations across different databases and got stuck. I have 3 fields I am playing with. I have a testdate field that is a date format. In addition to testdate I have a testtime field that is time format, and testminutes which is an integer. I want to concatenate these fields together to create a time stamp, using

my table is built like this:

```
create table Testing(
Primaryid int, 
testdate date, 
testtime time,
test minutes int);
```

End goal is to alter the table to add two columns like this:

```
alter table testing add column begintime timestamp;
alter table testing add column endtime timestamp;
```

and then populate those column begintime with

```
timestamp_from_parts(testdate, testtime)
```

which leads to the problem of needing to add the testminutes to this begintime field to find endtime.

```
timestamp_from_parts(testdate, testtime + --some conversion to turn testminutes into time--)
```

Main goal being to add testminutes to the timestamp of testdate + testtime

I want to do this so that I can get a timestamp of an events end time when provided with date, beginning time and duration.

Kind of stuck here, I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: "testdate field that is a date format" Are you using `varchar` data type or bona fide `date` data type? Please post the DDL (`create table ...` statement).

Comment: What exactly is your question? Does the Postgres transformation do what you want it to, and you want the analogous syntax for other DBMS types (if so, which ones)?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion here. The Postgres transformation performs what I want it to do, but I am now trying to do the same thing in a cloud DB Snowflake. Snowflake uses standard SQL syntax and the Postgres line does not work.

Answer (score 1):

In Snowflake, you can do it this way.

timeadd(minutes, test_minutes, timestamp_from_parts(testdate, testtime))